# Persisting SQLite in-Memory DB in Symfony/PHPUnit Tests

Tags: php, sqlite, symfony, doctrine

I'm using an SQLite in-memory for running the tests in phpunit. Since the tests take quite I long time I do not want to recreate the Schema after each test. But at the moment I have to because the Schema is not persisted between tests.

I have already tried overwriting the WebtestCase::tearDown() method, because it shuts down the kernel, but that did not help.

The database is configured like this:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection:   default
    connections:
        default:
            driver:   pdo_sqlite
            memory:   true
            path:     ~
```

Comment: this might help you, if your problem still exists: https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-testing-symfony-apps-with-a-disposable-database/